# pip not working after upgrade

Tags: 16.04, pip

So after installing something using pip3, I got the following error:

```
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Easy enough, so I run:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Now, when ever i run pip or pip3 I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
   from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

VERSION="16.04.5 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/error-after-upgrading-pip-cannot-import-name-main Same issue seems resolved.

Comment: fyi:  you need to upgrade your system (16.04.6 came out Feb-28, so you haven't fully-upgraded your system since at least then).  Upgrading some python packages this way can cause problems when you next do-release-upgrade, so remember to keep notes of what you upgrade outside of default packages, so you can remove it prior to next release-upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5221) in debian and its derivatives. So, it's better to stick to earlier versions of pip. To rollback, run:

```
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall
sudo python -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python-pip --reinstall
```